# Retrieve and edit data on page using Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I cant display my data, laravel's 404 page popping. 
Here is my foreach codes.

```
    @foreach($este as $row) 
      {{$row['価格']}}
      {{$row['間取り']}}
      {{$row['販売戸数']}}
      {{$row['総戸数']}}
      {{$row['専有面積']}}
      {{$row['専有面積']}}
      {{$row['その他面積']}}
      {{$row['所在階/構造 階建']}}
      {{$row['完成時期']}}
      {{$row['住所']}}
    @endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong here.

I want to edit table with css but data doesn't display.

My controller, and route is here:

```
public function sumos($id)
{
    $este = estates::all();
    return view('pages.sumo', ['este' => $este]);
} 

Route::get("sumo/{id}", "PagesController@sumos");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller and route to the following

```
public function sumos()
{
  $data['este'] = estates::all();
  return view('pages.sumo', $data);
} 

Route::get("sumo", "PagesController@sumos");
```

then your view to

```
@foreach($este as $row) 
  {{$row->価格}}
  {{$row->間取り}}
  {{$row->販売戸数}}
  {{$row->総戸数}}
  {{$row->専有面積}}
  {{$row->専有面積}}
  {{$row->その他面積}}
  {{$row->所在階/構造 階建}}
  {{$row->完成時期}}
  {{$row->住所}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: 404 page is gone but now error page coming " UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/var/www/html/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied "

Comment: That is because your storage folder is not readable, to get rid of that error, you need to change the persmission of your storage folder to be writable.

Comment: cd into your laravel folder then run the following command "sudo chmod -R 775 storage"

Comment: I cd into my laravel, and did that but still same error.

Comment: Systemctl restart httpd and chrcked the page. But still the samw problem

Comment: Okay man thanks I overcome that problem but now I am getting foreach error. syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) (View:

Comment: It means you have some errors before your foreach loop.. check the script you have before the foreach loop, it might be an open tag that has not been closed

Answer (score 1):

Don't return the value from the controller . Instead send the values to the view as parameter and then use it in your view

Like

```
public function sumos()
{
   $este = estates::get();
   return view('viewName', ['este' => $este]);
}
```

And in your view

```
@foreach($este as $row)
  write markup for your items here. 
@endforeach
```

Comment: I markup the data as you said. But still this time i can't retrieve it. I guess my markup is bad. Sorry for the simple quesition. I question at the top. By the way do we have to use echo for table tag in laravel too? is it the problem for my markup?

Answer (score 1):

firs you have to create a view file

[How to use views in Laravel?](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views)

then just use this construction:

```
public function sumos()
{
    $este = estates::all();
    return view('name_of_your_view_file', compact('este');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Actually get is for retrieve all the data from table  , 
2.After getting related data pass it on view 
public function sumos()
{
$este = estates::get();
return view("editPage" , compact('este'));
}
After View data in table using
@foreach($este as $est) //data here like html css @endforeach
add route to update data and pass it into controller
Then find related row using `
public function find($id){
$estates = estates::find($id);
//after changes 
$estates->save();
return redirect()->back();
}
`
```

Comment: mate thanks for commenting but I don't understand from here. add route to update data and pass it into controller
Then find related row using `
public function find($id){
$estates = estates::find($id);
//after changes 
$estates->save();
return redirect()->back();
} can you explain it a bit more. Do i need to add new route for my controller file?

Comment: and yes. I want to get all the data from database.

Comment: actually when you need to update the data you have to pass it again to controller to save at database, sorry for late reply

Comment: mate, I update the question can u check what I am missing there?

Comment: Hey mate, 
don't change the route code Route::get("sumo", "PagesController@sumos"); now add new route Route::get("change/{id}", "PagesController@find"); now this will call find() method , and call this route in view file , here you go :)

Comment: :) okay please send me message from here. I've got a couple question for you in this. If you will to help me out. kubilay.turgut@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

change your route to

```
Route::get("sumo/{id}", "PagesController@sumos");
```

Comment: added but now I am getting laravel's 404 page.

Comment: You are getting that error because the method "sumos" which was specified in the route is expecting a parameter

Comment: I gave it $id but still getting 404

Comment: So if you change your route to the following, you wound not get an error  Route::get("sumo/{id}", "PagesController@find");

Comment: I update the question and those are my new codes form. I said what you did but still getting 404 page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180680/discussion-between-kubilay-turgut-and-excellent-lawrence).